# Understanding the role of a variable accessing an array item/s using [ ]. (WatchAndCode related)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently working my way through a WatchAndCode course.

We are building a reminders/todo-style JavaScript app.

I am struggling to understand how the `[i]` in the `this.todos[i].todoText` section of the code works. The code does not function properly without it, so it is needed.

Please can somebody explain its role? I understand you can target a specific item in an array using brackets, but I am still confused how `i` works exactly.

Any help would be so appreciated. If possible, can there be no alterations to the code. I am a beginner so I'm taking it step-by-step, I understand there are probably more efficient ways to go about writing the code.

Here is the full code below:

```
var todoList = {
  todos: [],
  displayTodos: function() {
    if (this.todos.length === 0) {
      console.log('Your todo list is empty!');
    } else {
      console.log('My todos:');
      for (var i = 0; i < this.todos.length; i++) {
        console.log(this.todos[i].todoText);
      }
    }
  },
  addTodo: function(todoText) {
    this.todos.push({
      todoText: todoText,
      completed: false
    });
    this.displayTodos();
  },
  changeTodo: function(position, todoText) {
    this.todos[position].todoText = todoText;
    this.displayTodos();
  },
  deleteTodo: function(position) {
    this.todos.splice(position, 1);
    this.displayTodos();
  },
  toggleCompleted: function(position) {
    var todo = this.todos[position];
    todo.completed = !todo.completed;
    this.displayTodos();
  }
};
```

Thanks again

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays

Comment: `i` will hold an integer value which when used as `arr[i]` will return the item in `i`th position of the array arr. index starts from 0

Comment: Thank you for your replies everyone. You’ve all cleared it up for me, makes a lot more sense now. This is a great community and thank you for playing great parts in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the array consists of multiple objects, to access those objects you need to access their position in the array. The "i" in the for loop is just a variable that is going through numbers 0 to the length of the array. So the "i" will have the value 0 at start and todos[i] will actually access todos[0] (the first element of the array) and add the text from todoText to that element in the array, then the "i" becomes 1 because the for loop adds i++, it could have been written e.g i+2 if you need every 2nd element, etc.

Loops are used so you don't have to do that manually, it might be easier for you to understand if it was written manually at first :

```
this.todos[0].todoText
this.todos[1].todoText
this.todos[2].todoText
this.todos[3].todoText
this.todos[4].todoText
this.todos[5].todoText
this.todos[6].todoText
```

That's the code that happens in the loop basically so you don't have to write it all by yourself, accessing every object of the array and doing something with it. (in my example the array has 7 elements)

Hope this clarify's it a bit for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a property's value via:

```
 object.an_indentifier_that_matches_the_name
```

or

```
 object["an_expression_that_evaluates_as_a_string_that_matches_the_name"]
```

Arrays are just a type of object where property names that are integers (like `"1"`) are given special meaning.

You can use any expression (a string literal, a variable, a function call, etc) between the square brackets, so long as you get something which can be converted to a string at the end of it.

```js
var foo = ["a", "b", "c"];
var i = 2;
console.log(foo[2]);
console.log(foo["2"]);
console.log(foo[4 / 2]);
console.log(foo[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `i` in the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.todos.length; i++) {
  console.log(this.todos[i].todoText);
}
```

So you have to know how does loops works. First, you declare a variable `i` at the first part of the loop: `var i = 0;`. Then, in the middle, you have a condition, it will be checked in every loop iteration. If it evaluates to `true`, current iteration will be executed (this code will be executed: `console.log(this.todos[i].todoText);`). And finally, after one iteration, variable `i` will be increased by 1 (it happens here: `i++`).

So `i` is just a counter, it starts from 0 and increasing by 1 after every iteration. And in first iteration the actual `console.log` in the body of loop will be `console.log(this.todos[0].todoText);`, in the second it will be `console.log(this.todos[1].todoText);`, and so on, while this condition: `i < this.todos.length;` evaluates to `true`.

When you're doing `todos[0]`, it gets the first element from `todos` array.

For more info about *for loops*: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should read up on `arrays` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays

Lets assume `this.todos` equals this `array`:

```
[
   {todoText: 'Foo', completed: false},
   {todoText: 'Bar', completed: false},
]
```

If you view this like:

```
[
   0: {todoText: 'Foo', completed: false},
   1: {todoText: 'Bar', completed: false},
]
```

The number is the `index` for that entry in the array. Run snippet below to see output:

```js
let todos = [
   {todoText: 'Foo', completed: false},
   {todoText: 'Bar', completed: false},
];

console.log('if `i` equals 0 then the output of `todos[i]` is:')
var i = 0;
console.log(todos[i]);
console.log('if you want to get the `todoText` value for this entry then the value of `todos[i].todoText` is:')
console.log(todos[i].todoText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose we have this array:

```
this.todos = [
    /* Index "0" */ { todoText: 'my-text', otherProperty: 'blabla', },
    /* Index "1" */ { todoText: 'another-text', otherProperty: 'blabla', },
    /* Index "2" */ { todoText: 'last-text', otherProperty: 'blabla', },
];

// The line "this.todos[0].todoText" will show "my-text"
// The line "this.todos[2].todoText" will show "last-text"
```

In order to display the content of you todo-list, you have to pass through all of your todo elements, so you will make a loop through all of them with the `for` statement:

```
// Pass through your todo list.
// We began to the first element (with index "0"), the current step is stocked into "i" (var i = 0)
// Until we reach the last one (i < this.todos.length)
// When a step is over, we increment it of one (i++, or i += 1)

for (var i = 0 ; i < this.todos.length ; i++)
```

For each one, you write its content:

```
console.log(this.todos[i].todoText);
```

You precised that your first element in the index "0", so it's like you remplaced "i" by "0":

```
console.log(this.todos[0].todoText); // Remember, "this.todos[0].todoText" show "my-text".
```

And so on, until you loop through your last element:

```
console.log(this.todos[1].todoText); // Remember, "this.todos[1].todoText" show "another-text".
console.log(this.todos[2].todoText); // Remember, "this.todos[2].todoText" show "last-text".
```

Your loop is executed as long as `i < this.todos.length` is **true**. It ends after that because `this.todos[3]` does not exist and return **false**.